# Step over not working as expected in Eclipse Photon

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the below code for debugging:

```
    public class DebugTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        methodOne();
        System.out.println("main method");

    }

    private static void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("methodone");
        methodTwo();

    }

    private static void methodTwo() {
        methodThree();

    }

    private static void methodThree() {
        System.out.println("methodThree");

    }

}
```

Somehow the `step over(f6)` at method call `methodOne()` is not moving to next line but instead stepping into the function call. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Does your code compile? Possibly the code you are running is out of synch with the code displayed in the editor. Try to refresh/clean your project and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because methodTwo() doesn't exist. It jumps there because you want to jump over a method which causes a problem and instead of jump over it goes to the problem line.

If you replace in methodOne() printing and invoking methodTwo() you can see that it jumps to the line with methodTwo() not print.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    methodOne();
    System.out.println("main method");

}

private static void methodOne() {

    System.out.println("methodone");
    methodTwo();

}
```

If you create methodTwo() it normally jumps over this line.

Comment: I implemented the second method. Still the step over on method call methodOne() is going into methodOne() and not the next print of "main method"

Comment: Well, I have Eclipse Photon and it works fine now. Try to click on step over instead of using F6 and check if the result is correct. Maybe there is a problem with key mappings

Comment: Still the same with pressing the step over button. Just so we are on the same page. Hitting step over on the method call methodOne() should go to the next line of print statement "main method " right?

Comment: That's right. It jumps over the call methodOne(). So first it will print "methodone" then "methodThree" and then "main method"

Comment: So step over(f6) in case of methodOne() call behaves like step into(f5) since it does not print main method first?

Comment: First is invoking methodOne. Step over means &quot;invoke this method but dont go inside&quot; it let to debug faster because we dont want to see what is inside so we just step over this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184871/discussion-between-ghostrider-and-rafal-sokalski).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    methodOne();
    System.out.println("main method");

}

private static void methodOne() {

    System.out.println("methodone");
    methodTwo();

}
```

That's because I didn't implement the second method. Change the output statement and order, implement the second method and debug it.

Comment: I implemented the second method. Still the step over on method call methodOne() is going into methodOne() and not the next print of "main method"